# Location of field files in source format

Tags: salesforcedx

I understand the difference between mdapi format and source format, but there's one thing in the documentation that I find confusion with respect to field definitions and I'm wondering if I am missing something nuanced or if the docs are poorly worded.

Per the SFDX Developer Guide [Project Structure and Source Format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm) page:

> Some parts of the custom objects are extracted into in these subdirectories:
>
> businessProcesses
>   compactLayouts
>   **fields**
>   fieldSets
>   listViews
>   recordTypes
>   sharingReasons
>   validationRules
>   webLinks
>
> The parts of the custom object that are not extracted are placed in a file.
>   For objects, <*object*>.object-meta.xml
>   For fields,  <*field_name*>.field-meta.xml

The top part breaking down the subdirectories makes sense, as do the following two lines:

> The parts of the custom object that are not extracted are placed in a file.
>   For objects, <*object*>.object-meta.xml

The part that doesn't make sense to me is the next line:

> For fields,  <*field_name*>.field-meta.xml

This makes it sound as if not all fields will live in the fields subdirectory.

I've examined my own project in source format. The custom objects have their own <*object*>.object-meta.xml file, and individual custom fields each get their own <*field_name*>.field-meta.xml files in the object's fields subdirectory.

Is there a case, when working with source format, where there are field metadata files that do not live in the **fields** subdirectory for an object? Or is it just awkward terminology in the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I've observed (custom settings, platform events, normal custom objects, standard objects, and custom metadata), the fields are always in the fields directory, with the name `<field-name>.field-meta.xml`. This is simply confusing documentation.